# Hiding argument type from the user in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion

Suppose I'm writing a container class `template <typename T> class MyContainer` and for some reason I would like to pass objects of type `T` with their type hidden from the user. In particular I would like to ensure that any input to `MyContainer::Foo` goes first through `MyContainer::HideType`.

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
 public:
  ... constructors and stuff...

  HidesType& HideType(T&);      
  T& UnhideType(HidesType&);

  void Foo(HideType&);

  ... some other stuff...
};
```

Now I am wondering what HidesType can/should be. Some options are:

```
struct HidesType { 
  HidesType(T& data) : data_(data) { }
  T& data_; 
};
HidesType HideType(T& data) { return HidesType(data); }

union HidesType { T data_; };
HidesType& HideType(T& data) { return reinterpret_cast<HidesType&>(data); }

class HidesType : public T { };
HidesType& HideType(T& data) { return static_cast<HidesType&>(data); }
```

The problem with the first is that user can't keep `T` objects as

```
MyContainer<T>::HidesType tmp(HideType(t_obj));
```

because `tmp` will be invalid as soon as `t_obj` goes out of scope. Also, I'm not sure if the compiler will optimize away the HidesType completely.

The problem with the second is that I don't know if the reinterpret_cast is safe (e.g. won't there be any alignment issues?).

The problem with the third is that `T` might be marked `final` and HidesType& converts to T& implicitly.

Any thoughts or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

The main purpose of hiding is to make `HidesType` abstract and distinguishable from `T`.
It would be troublesome to explain all the context which led to this question. For now, let's assume that the function `MyContainer::Foo` essentially takes as an input `T`, however, I don't want the user to know/use that, in particular the interface might change in the future.

Correct usecase could be:

```
MyContainer<T>::HidesType handle = MyContainer<T>::HideType(t_obj);
... do something ...
... perhaps t_obj.~T(); ...
... do something ...
my_container.Foo(handle);
```

Invalid usecase:

```
MyContainer<T>::HidesType handle = MyContainer<T>::HideType(t_obj);
... do something ...
my_container.Foo(some_other_t_obj);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this hiding, exactly in what situation should the type be "hidden", and what do you mean by "hidden"?

Comment: An example of what should not be possible for client code, would go a long way towards clarifying things, I think.

Comment: I am not sure you can hide the type of a template from the user given that the user supplies the type in the first place.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf See the edit. The main purpose of hiding is to make `HidesType` abstract and distinguishable from `T`.

Comment: @Galik It is not the `T` itself that I want to hide, but the fact that `MyContainer::Foo` takes `T` as an argument.

Comment: Since the example includes destruction of the original `T` object, before `Foo` is called, that object must be copied or moved somewhere first, by `HideType` function. Is it added to the collection at that point? If so the handle type can just refer to, otherwise the handle type will have to contain a `T`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The handle should contain the object in question (e.g. by copy). The reason for this is that it is the user who memory-manages the handles (so yes, it is not really a "handle").

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want a type `H` that can only be instantiated or modified by `MyContainer<T>`.

An easy way to achieve that is a class type with `private` constructors and assignment operator, except move constructor, and having `MyContainer<T>` as `friend`.

You can `move` the specified `T` object into it, both for efficiency and in order to not needlessly require it to be copyable. If so then `H` will not guarantee to be copyable. But it should, as I see it, be movable.

Comment: See comment to Jarod42's answer. I'm trying to achieve zero-cost abstraction, i.e. the final code should look as HidesType was only a typedef of T. I'm not so sure that the compiler can optimize all of it.

Comment: @dtldarek: you would have to describe more in detail what cost you're seeing. i for sure ain't seeing no cost (on top of possibly copying a `T` object around). anyway, this smells a bit like **premature optimization**. the answer to optimization urge is to **MEASURE**. always do that when optimization urge sets in. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
public:
    class HandleType {
    public:
        friend class MyContainer;

        HandleType(const HandleType& rhs) = default;
        HandleType(HandleType&& rhs) = default;
        HandleType& operator =(const HandleType& rhs) = default;
        HandleType& operator =(HandleType&& rhs) = default;
    private:
        // only MyContainer can construct this class
        explicit HandleType(const T& t) : t(t) {}

    private:
        T t;
    };

    HandleType HideType(const T& t) { return HandleType(t); }
    T& UnhideType(HandleType& handle) { return handle.t; }

    void Foo(HandleType&);
};
```

Comment: Of course you can do something like that. The question is, will the compiler (in my case gcc 4.8) optimize the `HandleType` away at compile time? I would like the final assembly to be just as HandleType had never existed. This is the reason why I'm considering hacks union+casts.

Comment: I expect no overhead (except the copy in `HideType` which is mandatory by your specification).